# removing all entries from an object before a certain index javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object which looks as so:

```
const hours = {
   Monday: ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
   Tuesday: ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
   Wednesday:['9:00 am', '3:00 pm']
   Thursday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
   Friday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
   Saturday: "Closed",
   Sunday: "Closed",
}
```

I then get the current day of the week in a string format:

```
  const d = new Date();
  let day = d.getDay();

  const daysOfWeek = {
    1: 'Monday',
    2: 'Tuesday',
    3: 'Wednesday',
    4: 'Thursday',
    5: 'Friday',
    6: 'Saturday',
    7: 'Sunday'
  }


  const currentDayString = daysOfWeek[day]
```

I now need to create a new object that has the current day, up until sunday.

**ex output**

if the day is 'Friday' the `hours` obj should be:

```
{
  Friday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
  Saturday: "Closed",
  Sunday: "Closed"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please add the data in literal notation. is the data sorted?

Comment: iterate for(d=day; d<=7;d++)  out[daysOfWeek[d]]=response[daysOfWeek[d]]

Comment: you have all the data you need. just a for loop should do as thst mentioined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a `daysOfWeek` object to bridge the data between `hours` and `day` by storing the `keys` of `hours` as the values of `daysOfWeek` and the `keys` of `daysOfWeek` to match any of the possible values of `.getDay()` (1-7 for each day of the week).

Works well for **THIS** particular use case.

```js
const hours = {
   Monday: ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
   Tuesday: ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
   Wednesday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
   Thursday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
   Friday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
   Saturday: "Closed",
   Sunday: "Closed"
};

const d = new Date();
let day = d.getDay(); // if Friday, day === 5


const daysOfWeek = [ 
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday'
];

let thisWeekHours = {};

for (let i = day - 1; i < 7; i++) { // i === 5, 6, 7 (day value will never exceed 7), -1 because the array start at 0 and date at 1
  const hoursKey = daysOfWeek[i] // hoursKey === 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'
  thisWeekHours[hoursKey] = hours[hoursKey] // Setting property name to hoursKey, && value to hours at key of hoursKey
}

console.log(thisWeekHours);
```

For example, output for friday:

```
thisWeekHours = {
   'Friday': ['9:00', '3:00'],
   'Saturday': 'Closed',
   'Sunday': 'Closed'
}
```

Comment: @Elikill58 Absolutely!!

Comment: Nice ! I just convert code to snippet to make it easier to people to test themself

Answer (score 2):

Let today's day be ***d*** (ex: 'Monday', 'Tuesday') then,
and ***serverData*** be data we are getting from server so,

```
let found=0;
let result={}

Object.keys(daysOfWeek).forEach(key => {
  if (found) {
    result[daysOfWeek[key]] = serverData[daysOfWeek[key]]
  };
  if (daysOfWeek[key] === d) {
    found = 1;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say your starting day is "thursday", your result object could never be like this :

```
{
  Thursday: (2) ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'
  Friday: (2) ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm']
  Saturday: "Closed"
  Sunday: "Closed"
}
```

Cause JS orders an object alphabetically.

Try to push your results into an array like this (**data** been your server data):

```
let result = [];
for(let i=day; i <= Object.keys(daysOfWeek).length; i++)
{
     // result[daysOfWeek[i]] = data[daysOfWeek[i]]; // return object
     result.push(data[daysOfWeek[i]]); // return array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input data always contain all the week days in the right order, you can simply use the object properties index to determine which day it is:

```
const data = {
  Monday: ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
  Tuesday: ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
  Wednesday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
  Thursday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
  Friday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
  Saturday: 'Closed',
  Sunday: 'Closed',
};

const today = new Date().getDay();

const result = {};
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
  if (index >= today - 1) result[key] = value;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `reduce`

```js
const data = {
  Monday: ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
  Tuesday: ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
  Wednesday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
  Thursday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
  Friday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
  Saturday: 'Closed',
  Sunday: 'Closed',
};

const day = new Date().toLocaleString('en', { weekday: 'long' });

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((prev, [key, value]) => {
  if (key === day || day in prev) {
    prev[key] = value;
  }
  
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing it would be to step through some dates, starting with the current date `dt`. Show the opening times for the current day and then increment the date by one day. Repeat this process as long as `wd!== "Sunday"`.

```js
const opening={ // exactly as received from the server:
Friday:   ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
Monday:   ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
Saturday: "Closed",
Sunday:   "Closed",
Thursday: ['9:00 am', '3:00 pm'],
Tuesday:  ['9:00 am', '4:00 pm'],
Wednesday:['9:00 am', '3:00 pm']};

const dt=new Date();
do {
 var wd=dt.toLocaleString("en",{weekday:"long"});
 console.log(`${wd}: ${opening[wd]}`);
 dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1);
} while(wd!=="Sunday") // stop after "Sunday"
```

Doing it this way we *don't* require any "order" of the properties in the `opening` object. Keep in mind that [you cannot always rely on the order of properties in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/2610061) anyway!